# calling jquery replace content does not works when inside of function

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

so Im trying to: http://jsfiddle.net/LdeGC/1/

```
            if ($('.ui-droppable').find('span.closer').length == $('.ui-droppable').length) {
                alert('Listo ahora puedes simularlo');
                //if target is filled
                    $(".status1").replaceWith('<i class="icon-check"></i> Listo ahora puedes simularlo'); //update status
                //put composition into params
            } else {
                $(".status1").replaceWith('<i class="icon-edit"></i> Sigue');
            }
```

the alert works, but the jquery replaceWith inside the if does not, how can i fix it?

Comment: It is because during first execution the `status1` element is removed so in the second execution `$(".status1")` will not return anything

Answer (score 1):

Try with `html` instead of `replaceWith`.

Try Below

```
 if ($('.ui-droppable').find('span.closer').length == $('.ui-droppable').length) {
            alert('Listo ahora puedes simularlo');
            //if target is filled
                $(".status1").html('<i class="icon-check"></i> Listo ahora puedes simularlo'); //update status
            //put composition into params
        } else {
            $(".status1").html('<i class="icon-edit"></i> Sigue');
        }
```